# Create every package as one jar file using maven in pom.xml i want source code

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have requirement to generate jar files for selected packages i am new to maven  I am able to create jar for **src** folder but unable use

```
  <include>
```

and

```
  <exclude>
```

tags .I have spent almost 3 days i haven't got the solution.Please help me by provide good solution or pom.xml file.I want example code

Comment: As I understand your question, you need to exclude certain packages of your from getting compiled and bundled. As per my current understanding that is not possible. You can use exclude/include tag only with "resources" and not "sourceDirectory".

Comment: Why do you want to exclude packages to be packaged into a jar? Why are the classes in these packages are not relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [Maven shaded plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html). Especially the configurations to specify contents of uber jar.